# A non-singularity property for sets of real matrices

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $M_N(\mathbb{R})$ be the ring of $N\times N$ real matrices. We say that a couple $(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{V})$, with $\mathcal{U},\mathcal{V}\subseteq M_N(\mathbb{R})$ is *admissible* if, for every $A\in\mathcal{U}$ and $B\in\mathcal{V}$, the complex matrix $A+iB$ is non-singular. Of course, if the pair $(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{V})$ is admissible then the same is $(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{U})$.

A trivial example of admissible pair is $(\{0\},GL_{N}(\mathbb{R}))$, where $GL_{N}(\mathbb{R}))$ are the non-singular real matrices. A less trivial example is $(\mathrm{Sym}_{N}(\mathbb{R}),\mathrm{Sym}^+_{N}(\mathbb{R}))$, where $\mathrm{Sym}_{N}(\mathbb{R})$ are the symmetric matrices and $\mathrm{Sym}^+_{N}(\mathbb{R})$ are the symmetric positive definite matrices.

I am particularly interested in admissible pairs which are *maximal* with respect to the order $$(\mathcal{U},\mathcal{V})\lesssim(\mathcal{U'},\mathcal{V'})\Leftrightarrow \mathcal{U}\subseteq\mathcal{U'},\,\mathcal{V}\subseteq\mathcal{V'}.$$

For example, one may ask if the pair $(\mathrm{Sym}_{N}(\mathbb{R}),\mathrm{Sym}^+_{N}(\mathbb{R}))$ is maximal.

Analogous notions of admissible pair and maximal admissible pair can be also formulated for more general structure, for example associative real algebras with unit.

**Have been these objects already investigated?**